# Python Class inheriting Enum only vs. both Str, Enum

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, enums, python-class

Whats the difference between an enum class that inherits `Enum` compared with one that inherits `Str, Enum`, and when do you decide to use the one that has both `Str, Enum`?

I tried printing out the names and values of both types of enum instances, but they appear similar

```
from enum import Enum

class Animals(Enum):
    CAT = "cat"
    DOG = "dog"
print(Animals.CAT.name, type(Animals.CAT.name), Animals.CAT.value, type(Animals.CAT.value))

class Colors(str, Enum):
    BLUE = "blue"
    RED = "red"
print(Colors.RED.name, type(Colors.RED.name), Colors.RED.value, type(Colors.RED.value))
```

Output:

```
CAT <class 'str'> cat <class 'str'>
RED <class 'str'> red <class 'str'>
```

Comment: IMO, `class Colors(str, Enum):` defeats the entire purpose of an enum, so it should only be used for backwards compatibility or while trying to migrate the previous use of string constants to an enumeration

Comment: the difference is that in one case they are `str` objects, in the other, they aren't. So, for example, you can do `Colors.BLUE == "blue"` when ideally you would want that to raise an error.